# Creality ender 3 buildplate jamming

Tags: diy-3d-printer, creality-ender-3, build-plate

I bought a ender 3 a short time ago and yesterday i noticed a print failed. It seems like the buildplate jammed while trying to move along the y-axis so i replaced the v-shape wheels that keep it on the rails. However it still seems like my buildplate jams with every print en so my print layers move when the buildplate doesn't move making the layers not connect at the right places. Is there anyone who had this problem before and might know how to fix this?

Comment: Has it done this every time you've used it, or have some prints come out properly?

Comment: Every time since yesterday

Comment: That doesn't tell us if you used it without issue for two months, and this is a new problem, or if you just opened the box yesterday, and this has never worked properly.

Comment: I've been using it for a bit longer than a month without any problems.

Answer (score 1):

that sounds like layer shift... you might have one of these issues

- overtightened the carriage wheels.
- a loose Y-belt.
- something getting into the bed's cable, resulting in drag.